# Nginx rewrite rules are not working as expected

Tags: php, nginx, url, post

I have a website 
`https://dev.mywebsite.com/index.php?album=portraits`
which displays photo-albums dynamically based on a POST value.

I want to rewrite this URL to this:
`https://dev.mywebsite.com/portraits`

But my Nginx rewrite rule is not working. Nothing is happening when I enter `https://dev.mywebsite.com/index.php?album=portraits`. And no page is found when entering `https://dev.mywebsite.com/portraits`.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is the code I'm trying to use currently:

```
location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /album.php?album=$1 last;
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
location = /portraits { 
        rewrite ^/portraits?$ /index.php?album=portraits break; 
}
```

and this:

```
location = /album { 
        rewrite ^album/([a-z]+)/?$ album.php?album=$1 break; 
}
```

This is the entire nginx site-config file i'm using:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen 443 ssl;                                         
        root /config/www;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;
        server_name dev.mywebsite.com;

        ssl_certificate /config/keys/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /config/keys/cert.key;

        client_max_body_size 0;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args =404;
        }
    location / {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /album.php?album=$1 last;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # With php5-cgi alone:
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        }
}
```

Comment: You cannot have two `location /` blocks. Use `nginx -t` to test your configuration file. Is the php file called `album.php` or `index.php`?

Comment: Thank you I did not know that I couldn't have two. The file I am using is index.php. But I also tried to set it up in another way using album.php, because nothing was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file you *really* have is `index.php`, then you can rewrite (without any additional `location`) with:

```
rewrite ^/portraits$ /index.php?album=portraits last;
```

Keep the `location ~ \.php$ {` of course :)

Comment: Thank you this worked! I changed `portraits` to `([a-z]+)` and `$1` respectively as well, so it workes for all my albums.